# Xcode is not pulling the new files from git

Tags: xcode, git

I have my project in git and we are 2 programmers working in the project. User B using (xcode 8.2.1) added some files and pushed to remote.
User A using (xcode 8.0) also added some files committed changes clicked to pull it went through with out any messages, but the new files created by user B are not pulled. 
User A tried to push and this message shows up:

> "The local repository is out of date. Make sure all changes have been pulled from remote repository and try again"

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: If you would prefer an alternative GUI for Git to Xcode's, have a look at [Git Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/mac/).  (I have no financial interest, just a happy long-term user).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why I steer clear of of using Xcode's Git integration, it is very buggy and offer you less control resulting in not completely understanding what Git is doing...

Open up terminal (**cmd + space** and type "terminal" then press enter), navigate to your project's location by typing `cd` followed by the path to your project on the file system which can be done by dragging the project's directory from Finder into the Terminal app. This should get you something like:

`cd /Path/to/my/project/directory/`

Press enter. To confirm that you changed your present working directory type `pwd` followed by enter and it should regurgitate the path you gave to the `cd` command.

Now type `git status` it should spit out a git status in terminal, if it complains about the directory not being a valid git repository, make sure you specify a subdirectory of the project to `cd` and try again.

Assuming `git status` gives you some git status output type `git pull` followed by enter. Git will pull your comrade's changes and hopefully there won't be any conflicts...

Going forward I recommend you **DO NOT** use Xcode's Git integration, instead use Terminal and [Fork](https://git-fork.com/) for working with staging/unstaging and committing files. You will get a better understanding for Git this way and you will not be lied to by Xcode.

Comment: It worked thank you. I will start using the terminal